# JQuery sliding code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, iframe, jquery-animate

I am new to JQuery and am trying to make a div slide out from right to left, and then slide back in from left to right. The code I am using is:

```
   function addListeners()
   {
     document.getElementById('save_li').addEventListener('click', function () {

            $('#frame_div').animate({width:'toggle'});
            document.getElementById('frame_opened').src = "save.php";
            $('#frame_div').animate({width:'toggle'});
            }, false);  
      document.getElementById('recover_li').addEventListener('click', function () {
            $('#frame_div').hide("slide",{direction:"right"},1000);
            document.getElementById('frame_opened').src="recover.php";
            //$('#frame_div').animate({width:'toggle'});
            $('#frame_div').show("slide",{direction:"left"},1000);
            }, false);
   }
    window.onload=addListeners;
```

HTML:

```
<div src="save.php" class="frame_div" style="height: 500px; width: 574px; padding-left: 146px;">
  <iframe id="frame_opened" style="width: 100%;" height="100% overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden;" scrolling="no">
</div>
```

No errors are shown from either FireBug or WebDeveloper on Firefox, yet the code doesn't work. The `iframe` source changes with no animation.

Comment: Why are you combining jQuery and vanilla JS?

Comment: @Mooseman As I said, I am new to JQuery, so if I am combining it with vanilla JS, I am unaware of it :(. Can you please give a helping hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your code and made it all-jQuery. Make sure you are including `jquery.js` (or `jquery.min.v1.9.1.js` or similar) in your page. If you keep the line that requires jQuery UI (see comment in code), make sure you include jQuery UI's CSS and JS files.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save_li').click(function () {
        $('#frame_div').animate({width:'toggle'}, 1000);
        $('#frame_opened').attr('src','save.php');
        $('#frame_div').animate({width:'toggle'}, 1000);
    }); 
    $('#recover_li').click(function () {
        $('#frame_div').hide("slide",{direction:"right"}, 1000); // this line requires jQuery UI
        $('#frame_opened').attr('src','recover.php');
        $('#frame_div').show("slide",{direction:"left"}, 1000); // this line requires jQuery UI
    });
});
```

You were missing some required properties, such as the length of animation. (I set it to `1000`, which is 1 second.)

If you want to omit jQuery UI, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save_li').click(function () {
        $('#frame_div').hide(1000).show(1000);
        $('#frame_opened').attr('src','save.php');
    }); 
    $('#recover_li').click(function () {
        $('#frame_div').hide(1000).show(1000);
        $('#frame_opened').attr('src','recover.php');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="frame_div" style="height: 500px; width: 574px; padding-left: 146px;">
  <iframe src="save.php" id="frame_opened" style="width: 100%;" height="100% overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

The `src` attribute goes on the `iframe` element. If possible, move styles to CSS instead.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vy5AW/5/ using the HTML/CSS supplied by the OP in jsfiddle.net/vy5AW/2/

Comment: Is there another way to do this, without JQuery UI? As I said, I am new to JQuery, so introducing now JQuery UI besides will make it a little bit harder in future learning

Comment: @BujancaMihai I changed my answer.

Comment: Ok, I will try it, however this way will it fade , or slide in? And if it will slide in, will it slide in as desired?

Comment: Still just appears, doesn't look like sliding, I can't understand why. No error is shown, I added JQuery UI

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the rest of your HTML? I started one here: http://jsfiddle.net/vy5AW/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28616/discussion-between-mooseman-and-bujanca-mihai)

Comment: I only have one more question: why does the iframe appear at the bottom after the show()?

Comment: @BujancaMihai That's because of your CSS.